# Adding mobile network to Android device

Tags: android-source

I am developing a product using a version of aosp on a development board from ST Micro.
Thankfully ST provided a git tag to use but the release doesn't have any modile or cellular capability.

How, in AOSP, would I go about adding the 'Mobile network' tab under 'Network & internet' and how would I get an IP address from a provider using a supersim card?

Comment: Have you found the answer? Were you able to do it?

Comment: I did.  It was last year.  My company decided to avoid using Android for now though.

Comment: Could you please guide me as to how to do it? I was able to get mobile network tab, but it is greyed out. Also, i was not able to get the GUI network .